# Reading URL data from an external remote image during drag and drop

Tags: javascript, image, drag-and-drop

This will accept local files dragged-and-dropped and read the file data into the `files` string. How can I also read remote images dropped directly from the browser? i.e. Drag an image from Google image search into the Dropzone and read the image URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="dropzone"></div>

    <script>
      function handleFileSelect(evt){

        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

      }

      // Setup the dnd listener
      var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
      dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);

    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you planned to have drag functionality of remote files?

Comment: @hungryMind formData and XMLHttpRequest http://jsfiddle.net/7qfWz/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the files you are showing are not on local system, but remotely and displayed in browser. If you displaying image or image icon instead of file, make element as [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and allow to be dropped on other element. On drop write you code to copy or do something on server side.

Comment: I think the point here is that the image being dragged comes from another website.